# Does anyone know why my SEO and title become one?

Tags: plugins, php, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

```
<h1><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></h1>
```

Does anyone know why my SEO and title become one?
I use the above code to display the post title
When I change the title of SEO, this post title becomes the same
I want each to be different like the other sites on the other

my site : https://sanjamusics.ir/

Comment: Where you have added `<h1><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></h1>` ? If you have added this code to display the post title in single page you can slo use `get_the_title()` OR `the_title();`. Please refer this -> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/

Comment: I do not know how

Comment: Like this `<h1><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1>`. instead of your code use this.

Comment: In this case, the category names will have a problem
How can I create ( if else )for these codes?

<? php echo single_cat_title (''); ?> <? php echo get_the_title (); ?>